# Extrack JSON data in python Beatifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am Trying to Scrape content from Particular website (https://paytm.com/movies/coimbatore/) as JSON format in Python Using Beautiful soup Framework.. But I Dont know how to fetch the specific data

[image]

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


 URL = "https://paytm.com/movies/coimbatore/"
 r = requests.get(URL)   
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

 movies_showing_now_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'_1ZMxg'})
 movies_showing_now_div = soup.findAll('script',attrs={"type":"application/ld+json"})
 for title in movies_showing_now_div:     
  print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can just take all the `script` inside the `body` tag, and then you can use `json.loads()` to access the data you want.

You can try this:

**CODE:**

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
URL = "https://paytm.com/movies/coimbatore/"
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

movies_showing_now_div = soup.find('body').find_all('script',attrs={"type":"application/ld+json"})

movies = []

for script in movies_showing_now_div:
    jsonscript = json.loads(script.text)
    if jsonscript['@type'] and jsonscript['@type'] == 'Movie':
        movie = {
            'title': jsonscript['name'],
            'genre': jsonscript['genre']
        }
        movies.append(movie)

print(movies)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
[{'genre': 'drama', 'title': ' Vaanam Kottatum'},
 {'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Seeru'},
 {'genre': 'drama, thriller', 'title': 'Psycho'},
 {'genre': 'action, adventure, crime', 'title': 'Birds of Prey'},
 {'genre': 'horror, romance', 'title': 'Malang'},
 {'genre': 'action, drama', 'title': 'Darbar'},
 {'genre': 'drama', 'title': '1917'},
 {'genre': 'drama, comedy', 'title': 'Naadodigal 2'},
 {'genre': 'drama, historical, romantic', 'title': 'Shikara'},
 {'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Jaanu'},
 {'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Ala Vaikunthapurramuloo'},
 {'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Little Women'},
 {'genre': 'action, drama', 'title': 'Pattas'},
 {'genre': 'thriller, crime, mystery', 'title': 'Anjaam Pathiraa'},
 {'genre': 'action, thriller, crime', 'title': 'Bad Boys For Life'},
 {'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Anveshanam'},
 {'genre': 'drama', 'title': 'Dagaalty'},
 {'genre': 'horror, comedy', 'title': 'Sandimuni '},
 {'genre': 'action, thriller, crime', 'title': 'Bad Boys For Life'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, And then I want one more Help from your side.. I want to insert these data's into mysql table.. below the scipt..

Comment: for script in movies_showing_now_div:
    jsonscript = json.loads(script.text)
    if jsonscript['@type'] and jsonscript['@type'] == 'Movie':          
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_movies (movie_name) VALUES (%s)",(movie_name))

Answer (score 1):

I've used title.text in order to just extract the text present in the script tag.
That text was json data so I just used json.loads to tranform it into a dictionary and then extracted the features you needed and put them in a list for future use.

Given the requirements (extract **name**, **genre**, **image**) here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

URL = "https://paytm.com/movies/coimbatore/"
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

movies = []
movies_showing_now_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': '_1ZMxg'})
movies_showing_now_div = soup.findAll('script', attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"})
for title in movies_showing_now_div:
    json_data = json.loads(title.text)
    if '@type' in json_data:
        if json_data['@type'] == "Movie":
            movie = {"name": json_data["name"],
                     "genre": json_data["genre"],
                     "image": json_data["image"]
                     }
            movies.append(movie)

for movie in movies:
    print("Name:\t{}\nGenre:\t{}\nImage:\t{}\n".format(movie['name'], movie['genre'], movie['image']))
```

**Example Output**

```
Name:   Vaanam Kottatum
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Vaanam-Kottatum-Tamil-Web-poster-705x750-213b1eaf-2e77-4825-9ee8-ae117d354592.jpg

Name:   Seeru
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/seeru_web_705x750_psd-1028fe75-3147-4732-95f4-4e05e558bce5.jpg

Name:   Naan Sirithal
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Naan-Sirithal-705x750-2042f291-c470-43db-a3ab-21400202a090.jpg

Name:   Psycho
Genre:  drama, thriller
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/psycho_web_705x750_psd-e1000de5-d47e-455c-a294-9309a725e30b.jpg

Name:   Malang
Genre:  horror, romance
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/malang-poster_web_705x750_psd-25688127-de49-4bed-94a1-a69bc69e00c4.jpg

Name:   Darbar
Genre:  action, drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Darbar-tamil-Web-poster-705x750-7ace9f7d-1fe8-4506-b920-f1c72a4d552f.jpg

Name:   World Famous Lover
Genre:  drama, romance
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/World-Famous-Lover-Telugu-Web-poster-705x750-04e70194-d75a-4309-89a4-2d636c71a08b.jpg

Name:   1917
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/1917-Web-poster-705x750-35a92d72-89f8-4ee3-9da3-da1e35ebdef9.jpg

Name:   Harley Quinn: Birds Of Prey
Genre:  action, adventure, crime
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/_Birds-of-Prey-Web-poster-705x750-41265fe7-ea32-49ae-b3d8-72fbca2e7970.jpg

Name:   Parasite
Genre:  drama, thriller
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Parasite-Korean-Web-poster-705x750-4ca2d1d5-3f94-4af0-9c41-ab564dc455d8.jpg

Name:   Ayyappanum Koshiyum
Genre:  action, comedy
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Ayyappanum-Koshiyum-malyalam-Web-poster-705x750-7c94eb30-b197-4a1c-9dd3-e920dbb85592.jpg

Name:   Varane Avashyamund
Genre:  action, drama, family
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Varane-Avashyamund-Malayalam-Web-poster-705x750-83264d5e-6fa8-40b6-8527-50eb44b4b8c8.jpg

Name:   Naadodigal 2
Genre:  drama, comedy
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/NAADODIGAL-2-Tamil-Web-poster-705x750-1f6c24ff-80bd-41b2-8b41-aae87070eff8.jpg

Name:   Shikara
Genre:  drama, historical, romantic
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/SHIKARA--705x750-3fbabda6-3093-493e-876c-47fc8100d9f4.jpg

Name:   Jaanu
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Jaanu-Web-poster-705x750-0f3cc028-7ea1-4410-a5c1-dff19844b5c3.jpg

Name:   Ala Vaikunthapurramuloo
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Ala-Vaikunthapuramulo-Web-poster-705x750-f916ecdc-d07b-4b0e-959c-1bbcf8e2cd40.jpg

Name:   Anjaam Pathiraa
Genre:  thriller, crime, mystery
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/aanjam-pathiraa_web_705x750_psd-4b4922dd-0877-4db1-ac7e-733bda22ccf9.jpg

Name:   Pattas
Genre:  action, drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Pattas-Tamil-Web-poster-705x750-6c6b62fa-2590-44ea-918b-cce68a1ac5f0.jpg

Name:   Anveshanam
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/anveshanam_web_705x750_psd-495caeb6-2b1e-4001-8e37-6bf925ea075d.jpg

Name:   Little Women
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/little-women_web_705x750_jpg-77420f75-8e39-4db5-bf03-06298ec93c91.jpg

Name:   Dagaalty
Genre:  drama
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Dagaalty-Tamil-Web-poster-705x750-0b4c383d-506c-478c-8979-0654a73bd357.jpg

Name:   Sandimuni
Genre:  horror, comedy
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Sandimuni-Tamil-Web-poster-705x750-ac0e354d-e3a6-4f00-a5e6-88f7f2695b4e.jpg

Name:   Bad Boys For Life
Genre:  action, thriller, crime
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Bad-Boys-for-Life-Web-poster-705x750-4bbd571f-ca3d-4667-b01d-f38c175511bb.jpg

Name:   Bad Boys For Life
Genre:  action, thriller, crime
Image:  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets.paytm.com/images/cinema/Bad-Boys-for-Life-Web-poster-705x750-b828b281-afe3-4eb1-9f33-42ecddc70496.jpg
```

Comment: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_movies (movie_name,genre,image,language,duration) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(movie['name'],movie['genre'],movie['image'],movie['inLanguage'],movie['duration']))

Comment: I am trying insert the data in mysql.. but its not working.. pls help me

Comment: Hi @Arunsankar !

Which is the error you get? Maybe it is a good idea to open a new question with this...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

URL = "https://paytm.com/movies/coimbatore/"
movies = []

r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')  # lxml is faster than html.parser

movies_showing_now_div = soup.find('body').findAll('script', attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"})

for div in movies_showing_now_div:
    movie_dict = {}
    data = json.loads(div.text)
    if data["@type"] == "Movie":
        movie_dict["movie_name"] = data["name"]
        movie_dict["genre"] = data["genre"]
        movies.append(movie_dict)

print(movies)
```